# ToggleButton behaves differently on Touch Device

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have this piece of XAML code here :

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ColorPickerButton" 
                          Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource Segment0}" 
                          Checked="ColorPickerChecked" 
                          Unchecked="ColorPickerUnchecked">
                <ToggleButton.Transitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="100" FromVerticalOffset="100"/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </ToggleButton.Transitions>
            </ToggleButton>
```

It is working fine on my computer ; and by working fine I mean methods `ColorPickerChecked` and `ColorPickerUnchecked` are correctly called when I click on the `ToggleButton`. However, on a touch device (a Microsoft Surface) these methods aren't called at all. However the event `Tapped` is correctly raised if I add it in the XAML. For now, here is the method called when the `Tapped` event is raised:

```
private void ColorPickerButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var s = sender as ToggleButton;
            if(s != null)
                s.IsChecked = !s.IsChecked;
        }
```

Which I find kind of sloppy. Why does it behave differently? Is there something I am missing here? I recall using `ToggleButton` in other applications and in my memories it seemed to work fine... But not here!

Cheers

Comment: I want the event "Checked" to be raised, not "Clicked". Are you saying that "Clicked" event on a ToggleButton automatically raise the "Checked"/"Unchecked" events while the "Tapped" event does not?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, misread the question.

Comment: So why not just go by the IsChecked bool like you're doing? If that's the condition (like what a ToggleButton is generally used for) there shouldnt be anything sloppy about it.

Comment: There is more behind the scene and it is crucial that both version works exactly the same without preprocessing. Also, it really should work shouldn't it?

Comment: Well, do you want to fire off whatever its doing by a Tap/Clicked/MouseLeftButtonDown or by the condition of the IsChecked bool? Guess that question would lead to your answer. Tap etc is generic, IsChecked I would think is what you're looking for to fire off the magic in the back.

Comment: @RedPolygon - The `Checked` and `Unchecked` events fire properly for me when I use my Surface. (Yes, I am using touch to press the button and not the mouse). All I have is a `Grid` with a `StackPanel` inside, with a `ToggleButton` inside. My `ToggleButton` uses your xaml code above. My guess is that one of your `ToggleButton` container controls is interfering with the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events.

Comment: @chue that was exactly the problem! the ToggleButton was contained in a canvas and removing the canvas made the control behave correctly. Post that as an answer so I can accept it! (but still, it is working on a computer and not on a touch device which is weird, but anyway it is working now).

Comment: @RedPolygon - Glad that solved it! I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that one of your `ToggleButton`'s container controls is interfering with these events.

I tried your xaml code above inside a simple container (inside a `StackPanel` inside a `Grid`), and the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events fire for me.

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it a little differently. In the following blog post, the cause and a solution to the problem is described: http://candritzky.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/wpf-button-in-wpf-bing-maps-mapitemscontrol-not-reacting-to-touch-events/